# HTMLImageElement node instead of real image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm dynamically creating some image elements, everything is good but when i am trying to wrap this images in `li` elements i have strange response in DOM, which is: `[object HTMLImageElement]`.

This is the code, please note that element crating function and requireJS are working fine, the problem is by wrapping side.

```
$.each(images, function(key, value){
    requirejs(["globals"], function(){
        var _image = createEl("img", {
            className: "thumb",
            src: photosTempUrl + value
        });
        var image = $('<li>' + _image + '</li>');
        image.appendTo('#js-thumbsBox');
    });
});
```

Thx for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created an element (`_image = createEl(...)`) and are then *converting it to a string* (which, just like any object, results in `[object ConstructorName]`)

Instead, try:

```
var image = $("<li>");
image.append(_image);
image.appendTo("#js-thumbsBox");
```

Comment: Lukas - Can you upvote and accept the answer please. Keeps the site running smoothly.